# Kotlin - Dagger 2 is is not injecting objects

Tags: android, kotlin, dagger-2

I have created simple application to test Dagger 2 injection. I think I have written everything propertly but in runtime I get this error.

```
kotlin.UninitializedPropertyAccessException: lateinit property app has not been initialized
```

It turns out that none of my dependencies are injected.

Here is my example:

Component:

```
@Component(modules = arrayOf(AppModule::class))
interface AppComponent {
    fun inject(app : App)
}
```

IMainomponent:

```
@Component(modules = arrayOf(MainPresenterModule::class))
interface IMainComponent {
    fun inject(mainView : MainActivity)
}
```

AppModule:

```
@Module
class AppModule(val app: App) {
    @Provides @Singleton fun provideApp() : App = app
}
```

Main presenter module:

```
@Module
class MainPresenterModule(private val view: MainActivity) {
    @Provides
    fun provideView() : MainActivity = view
}
```

Use in activity:

```
class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity(), IMainView {

    @Inject lateinit var presenter : MainPresenter
    @Inject lateinit var app : App

    val component: IMainComponent by lazy {
        DaggerIMainComponent
                .builder()
                .mainPresenterModule(MainPresenterModule(this))
                .build()
    }

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)
        component.inject(this)
    //        presenter.beginMessuring()

        if(app != null) // fails here because all lateinits are null
        {

        }
    }

    override fun toastMessage(message: String) {
        Toast.makeText(this, message, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show()
    }
}
```

Could you tell me if I am doing something wrong.

Gradle dagger settigns:

```
kapt 'com.google.dagger:dagger-compiler:2.13'
implementation 'com.google.dagger:dagger:2.13'
```

EDIT:

I have notieced that when I configure Dagger graph using for example this,

```
DaggerIMainComponent.builder().mainPresenterModule(MainPresenterModule(this)).build()
```

I get info that mainPresenterModule method is deprecated. I found info that android studio usually shows that info when it cant find any @Inject of components provided by builded module.

Comment: try replacing ``@Inject`` with ``@field:Inject`` or ``@set:Inject``. Not sure if it helps.

Comment: Yeah `@field:Inject`

Comment: Why are you using `dagger:2.5` and not the latest version which is `dagger 2.13`?

Comment: @DavidRawson I used 2.5 because that was the version used in tutorial which I followed and I just wanted to be sure that gradle configuration is right. I have changed it to 2.13 as you said.

Comment: @Fred, I tried \@field:Inject without any success :(

Comment: Can you try a clean and rebuild now?

Comment: Yeah, I did it, and still the same :(

Comment: Please include your IMainComponent. Does it contain an inject method for MainActivity? Or did you use a Supertype?

Comment: @DavidMedenjak Firstly I tried using supertype without any success so now it looks as I pasted.

Comment: show us your MainPresenterModule

Comment: Ok I've done that

Comment: Please update your question with the code you actually use and the error you face. I don't think that the code as you include it in your question would compile, since I can see no subcomponent or component dependency, and the `App` dependency can't be satisfied. This will not compile, so the runtime error seems weird to me.

Comment: I got the simillar problem and the reason was, that I didn't change the Application name in manifest (in your case it will be App)